# assertEquals fails for equivalent Jackson objects created in different ways

Tags: java, junit, jackson-databind

So I am wondering why two objects are failing in my unit test (Junit 5) when they are created differently.

First way:

```
static ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode output = mapper.convertValue(jsonTransform, JsonNode.class);
```

Second way:

```
JsonNode expectedOutput = mapper.readTree(jsonString);
```

And then asserted:

```
Assertions.assertEquals(expectedOutput, output);
```

The failure:

```
is org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode@d6e7bab<jsonString> but was: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode@5fa07e12<jsonString>
```

Further, if I then edit the assertion to be:

```
Assertions.assertEquals(expectedOutput, mapper.readTree(output.toString()));
```

It will pass. So what concept is causing the first assertion to fail?

Comment: What type is the "jsonTransform" variable that  you are passing into convertValue ?

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @djharten it is of type Object.

Answer (score 1):

`assertEquals` will call this method to find if the two objects are equal:

```java
 private static boolean isEquals(Object expected, Object actual) {
        return expected.equals(actual);
    }
```

I would take a look at the `equals()` method in `JsonNode` to see what is being checked.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue, the only solution I have found so far is to make use of:

```
Assertions.assertEquals(expectedOutput.toPrettyString(), output.toPrettyString());
```

I know it's not optimal but does the job. Funny thing is InteliJ says that the "Contents are identical" on the Comparison Failure but the test fails if I remove the `toPrettyString()`